# fubini's theorem, multivariable integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral

$$ \int_{[0,1]^n} \max{(x_1,x_2,x_3, \cdots,x_n)} \,dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n $$

Any hints comments are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A variation on the same thing: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181678/evaluating-int-in-left-min-1-le-i-le-nx-i-right-alpha-dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of points
$$
H = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n): x_i=x_j=\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \text{ for some } i\not=j\}
$$
lies inside the union of hyperplanes $\bigcup_{i\not=j}\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n): x_i=x_j\}$. Hence it has zero measure. Therefore
\begin{align}
&\int_{[0,1]^n} \max{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)} \,dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n\\
=&n \int_{[0,1]^n} x_1{\bf 1}(x_2,\cdots,x_n< x_1)\,dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n\tag{a}\\
=&n \int_0^1x_1\int_0^1 {\bf 1}(x_2<x_1)\int_0^1 {\bf 1}(x_3<x_1)\cdots\int_0^1 {\bf 1}(x_n<x_1)\,dx_n\cdots dx_2\,dx_1\tag{b}\\
=&n \int_0^1x_1\int_0^{x_1} \int_0^{x_1} \cdots\int_0^{x_1} \,dx_n\cdots dx_2\,dx_1\\
=&n \int_0^1x_1^n\,dx_1,
\end{align}
where ${\bf 1}(\cdot)$ denotes the indicator function, equality $(a)$ is due to symmetry and the fact that $H$ has measure zero, and $(b)$ is due to Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thanks. But should that $n$ in front be $n!$. I'm not sure how that comes about. Can you please explain a little more.?. I thought I knew how to do this problem if we had min instead of max, but I'm not so sure now.

Comment: @user54755 For min, flip the direction of the inequality sign inside each ${\bf 1}(\cdot)$, so you get $n\int_0^1x_1^n(1-x_1)^ndx_1$.

Comment: At a wild guess, I would imagine the average of the $\min$ + $\max$ would be $\frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: @copper.hat You are certainly right, but personally, I find it more intuitive to imagine $E(\min)=E(1-\max)$ by symmetry than to imagine that $(E(\min)+E(\max))/2=1$ or $E((\min+\max)/2)=1$.

Comment: @user54755 No, the multiplicative factor is $n$, not $n!$. There are only $n$ cases: either $x_1$ is the maximum, $x_2$ is the maximum, ..., or $x_n$ is the maximum. We don't care how the $n-1$ smaller $x_j$s are ordered.

Comment: @user1551: I think we have the same idea expressed slightly different: You $E(\min) = E(1-\max)$, Me $E(\min+\max) = E(1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat (Oops, typo. $E(\min+\max)=1$. Nevermind.) Yes, the ideas are the same, but I am not smart enough to jump to $E(\min+\max)=1$ (not to say $E((\min+\max)/2)=1/2$) directly. :-D

Comment: @user1551:Thanks so much. But shouldn't that third integral from the left on (b) be \int_0^1 1(x_3<x_1)?

Comment: @user54755 You are right. It's now corrected.

Comment: @user1551: What exactly did you mean above by E(max), E(min) etc.,?

Comment: @user54755 The expected value of the maximum/minimum over the unit cube under uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the integral you have can be written as
$$n \int_{x_1=0}^1 \int_{0\leq x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n \leq x_1} x_1 dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n = n \int_{x_1=0}^1 x_1^n dx_1 = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$$