# $\int_{I^n}(\min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i)^a dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[0,1]$.
Find 
$$\int_{I^n} \left(\min_{1\leq i\leq n} x_i \right)^a dx,$$ 
for $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
Please help to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Just break the sum according to which $x_i$ is the minimum.

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{[x_i,1]^{n-1}} x_i^a dx$ an then?

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^1 \left( \int_{[x_i,1]^{n-1}} \prod_{j\ne i} dx_j \right) x_i^a dx_i  = n \int_0^1 t^a (1-t)^{n-1} dt$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181678/evaluating-int-in-left-min-1-le-i-le-nx-i-right-alpha-dx